# Workstation and Ace License

Tags: vmware-workstation

Previously I had workstation 6.52 installed and I was able to create and use pocket ace packages on the same machine they were created. After upgrading to workstation 7 I am receiving license errors after creating a new ace package and attempting to use it. Ace stops and prompts for an ace license.

According to Workstation Manualhttp://pubs.vmware.com/ws7_ace26/ws_user/ace_inst_install.24.16.html
"If you are not using an ACE volume license key, be aware that when you deploy a Pocket ACE to a portable media device, you should enter an ACE client license immediately. The Pocket ACE will run locally on that copy of Workstation, but if it is moved to another unlicensed device without having the ACE client license entered, it will not power on."

Despite what the manual says I am not experience this behavior. Is anyone else having this problem or have an idea of how to address it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to ask VMware support.

Comment: It is the easiest aswear, yeah? :)

Comment: Yes, and it's part of what you pay them for.